Smartcard error 0x8010002f when using Chilkat DLL function "TransmitHex()"
I use:

Gemalto IDBridge K30
Windows 10
Delphi
Chilkat Delphi DLL

I need to get ICCID out of a SmartCard, but when I use TransmitHex() from Chilkat DLL I always get the error code:

0x8010002f

First I tried the example from Chilkat: https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/pcsc_get_card_uid.asp
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  scard: HCkSCard;
  success: Boolean;
  json: HCkJsonObject;
  name: PWideChar;
  state: PWideChar;
  vendorName: PWideChar;
  systemName: PWideChar;
  cardAtr: PWideChar;
  cardWindowsMiniDriver: PWideChar;
  cardWindowsCryptoProvider: PWideChar;
  cardWindowsKeyStorageProvider: PWideChar;
  serialNumber: PWideChar;
  i: Integer;
  count_i: Integer;
  bdRecv: HCkBinData;
  numBytes: Integer;
begin
  // This example requires the Chilkat API to have been previously unlocked.
  // See Global Unlock Sample for sample code.

  scard := CkSCard_Create();

  // First establish a context to the PC/SC Resource Manager
  success := CkSCard_EstablishContext(scard,'user');
  if (success = False) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
      Exit;
    end;

  // Use your own smart card reader name here.
  success := CkSCard_Connect(scard, CkSCard__connectedReader(scard),'shared','no_preference');
  if (success = False) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
      Exit;
    end;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('Connected reader: ' + CkSCard__connectedReader(scard));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Active protocol: ' + CkSCard__activeProtocol(scard));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ATR: ' + CkSCard__cardAtr(scard));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Reader Status: ' + CkSCard__readerStatus(scard));

  //  Send the APDU command 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
  bdRecv := CkBinData_Create();
  success := CkSCard_TransmitHex(scard,CkSCard__activeProtocol(scard),'FFCA000000',bdRecv,32);
  if (success = True) then
    begin

      Memo1.Lines.Add('Received: ' + CkBinData__getEncoded(bdRecv,'hex'));

      // The UID is the returned data without the final 2 bytes.
      numBytes := CkBinData_getNumBytes(bdRecv);
      if (numBytes > 2) then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('UID: ' + CkBinData__getEncodedChunk(bdRecv,0,numBytes - 2,'hex'));
        end;

    end
  else
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
    end;

  // Disconnect from this reader.
  success := CkSCard_Disconnect(scard,'leave');
  if (success = False) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
    end;

  // Applications should always release the context when finished.
  success := CkSCard_ReleaseContext(scard);
  if (success = False) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
    end;

  CkSCard_Dispose(scard);
  CkBinData_Dispose(bdRecv);
end;

What I got was:

UnlockBundle: 
Oh yeah
Test
Test1
Test2
0: Gemalto USB SmartCard Reader 0
Connected reader: Gemalto USB SmartCard Reader 0
Test3
Test4
Connected reader: Gemalto USB SmartCard Reader 0
Active protocol: T0
ATR: 3B9F96801FC68031E073FE211B66D00221AB11180180
Reader Status: specific
ChilkatLog:
  TransmitHex(1844ms):
    DllDate: Jun 29 2024
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.99
    UnlockStatus: 1
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: Delphi DLL
    VerboseLogging: 1
    transmit(1844ms):
      PcscErrorCode: 0x8010002f
      SCardTransmit failed.
    --transmit
    Failed.
  --TransmitHex
--ChilkatLog


Test5
Test6
Test7


Later I found out that Smartcards which need a PIN don't have a UID. But I would guess that would cause a different error.
I also tried something to get the ICCID which I would need:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  scard: HCkSCard;
  success: Boolean;
  json: HCkJsonObject;
  name: PWideChar;
  state: PWideChar;
  vendorName: PWideChar;
  systemName: PWideChar;
  cardAtr: PWideChar;
  cardWindowsMiniDriver: PWideChar;
  cardWindowsCryptoProvider: PWideChar;
  cardWindowsKeyStorageProvider: PWideChar;
  serialNumber: PWideChar;
  i: Integer;
  count_i: Integer;
  bdRecv: HCkBinData;
  numBytes: Integer;
begin
  // This example requires the Chilkat API to have been previously unlocked.
  // See Global Unlock Sample for sample code.

  scard := CkSCard_Create();

  // First establish a context to the PC/SC Resource Manager
  success := CkSCard_EstablishContext(scard,'user');
  if (success = False) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
      Exit;
    end;

  // Use your own smart card reader name here.
  success := CkSCard_Connect(scard, CkSCard__connectedReader(scard),'shared','no_preference');
  if (success = False) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
      Exit;
    end;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('Connected reader: ' + CkSCard__connectedReader(scard));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Active protocol: ' + CkSCard__activeProtocol(scard));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ATR: ' + CkSCard__cardAtr(scard));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Reader Status: ' + CkSCard__readerStatus(scard));

  //Get ICCID
  //  Send the APDU command 0xA0, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x3F, 0x00
  bdRecv := CkBinData_Create();
  success := CkSCard_TransmitHex(scard,CkSCard__activeProtocol(scard),'A0A40000023F00',bdRecv,32);
  if (success = True) then
    begin

      Memo1.Lines.Add('Received: ' + CkBinData__getEncoded(bdRecv,'hex'));

      // Select MF
      numBytes := CkBinData_getNumBytes(bdRecv);
      if (numBytes > 2) then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Select MF: ' + CkBinData__getEncodedChunk(bdRecv,0,numBytes - 2,'hex'));
        end;

    end
  else
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
    end;

  //  Send the APDU command 0xA0, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x2F, 0xE2
  bdRecv := CkBinData_Create();
  success := CkSCard_TransmitHex(scard,CkSCard__activeProtocol(scard),'A0A40000022FE2',bdRecv,32);
  if (success = True) then
    begin

      Memo1.Lines.Add('Received: ' + CkBinData__getEncoded(bdRecv,'hex'));

      // Select ICCID
      numBytes := CkBinData_getNumBytes(bdRecv);
      if (numBytes > 2) then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Select ICCID: ' + CkBinData__getEncodedChunk(bdRecv,0,numBytes - 2,'hex'));
        end;

    end
  else
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
    end;

  //  Send the APDU command 0xA0, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A
  bdRecv := CkBinData_Create();
  success := CkSCard_TransmitHex(scard,CkSCard__activeProtocol(scard),'A0B000000A',bdRecv,32);
  if (success = True) then
    begin

      Memo1.Lines.Add('Received: ' + CkBinData__getEncoded(bdRecv,'hex'));

      // Read the 10 bytes of ICCID EF
      numBytes := CkBinData_getNumBytes(bdRecv);
      if (numBytes > 2) then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Read ICCID: ' + CkBinData__getEncodedChunk(bdRecv,0,numBytes - 2,'hex'));
        end;

    end
  else
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
    end;
  //END

  // Disconnect from this reader.
  success := CkSCard_Disconnect(scard,'leave');
  if (success = False) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
    end;

  // Applications should always release the context when finished.
  success := CkSCard_ReleaseContext(scard);
  if (success = False) then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(CkSCard__lastErrorText(scard));
    end;

  CkSCard_Dispose(scard);
  CkBinData_Dispose(bdRecv);
end;

But the results for the error are still the same.

The products are called Delphi (with H) and Chilkat (only one L).

According to many Google search results, the error code 0x8010002f means "A communications error with the smart card has been detected." Can't it be simply that? A problem with the concrete card or card reader?

Plus, nothing new, but for reference, the official documentation page for Delphi DLL: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/dd_CkSCardRef.html

@MatthiasB Well I also did tried a different Card and got the same problem so I don't think that the card is the problem. I don't know about the reader thought but isn't it strange that it would even connect and give me ATR? Does this not imply that it should work? Dunno, but I also think trying a different reader might be for the better.

Some remarks:
I assume, that you understand ICCID as unique serial number of the card. These are wildly varying (you might even not be able to get it at all for a given smart card) and the way to get it also varies depending on the card. See this question for details.
What the code from first example apparently attempts  is, to send a special APDU ("FFCA..") and expect the ICCID as response. This is a reader specific command and may be the wrong one, even if defined by PCSC V3.2.
The code from the second example uses CLA byte A0 which may be correct for your card, but you don't seem to provide a hint, what card you are actually addressing, since Gemalto IDBridge K30 is a reader.

The First Command was a example from Chilkat, wich does not attempt to get the ICCID, it tries to get UID, in the second example this is what I intended to do.
